# Google Maps activity crashes with SIGSEGV on back button

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, segmentation-fault

I have multiple Google maps activities in my app, and when either of them return to the previous activity, either by back button or

```
finish();
```

, I get the following error:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x646e413c (code=1), thread 2755 (Thread-186)
```

Which may be related to the message below it:

```
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

This only happens when leaving maps activities, not any other activities, but then the app continues to run as normal after crashing. Do I need do anything else to destroy the map when leaving the activity? Maybe there's a memory leak?

Comment: Are you doing anything with the C/C++ code and the NDK? Are you using any libraries that use C/C++ code and the NDK?

Comment: I'm not using anything related to the NDK, just the standard Java libraries.

Comment: What device is this crashing on? A `SIGSEGV` should only result from a bug in native code, whether that is your native code, a library's native code, another process' native code (e.g., Play Services Framework), or the OS itself.

Comment: It's crashing on a Nexus 5 emulator. I am using the newest version of Android Studio, so there's always the chance that it's a bug.

Comment: I think it's a bug with the emulator, because everything worked fine when I ran it on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is an emulator bug. Tested the app on my phone and nothing of the sort occurred.